# Java - password policy validation

Tags: java, regex, validation, web

In my web application I have the following requirement. I have the following constraints while setting the password when the user signs up for first time.

1. Passcode should contain 6 digits. (Eg 132715)
2. Only numbers can be entered
3. No ascending/descending numbers allowed (Eg 123456, 654321 - not allowed)
4. 3 (or more) same number cannot be repeated (Eg 121715, 232254 - not allowed).

Can anyone please clarify if this can be done through Regular Expression or is it better to implement through Java. If possible can anyone please provide me a sample code?

Comment: This can be done with regular expressions. However, you cannot just hop on and expect an answer. Please show us some things you have tried or looked into on the subject.

Comment: I think only 1 and 2 can be done with regex.

Comment: 1 and 2 are easy, length match and match on ^[\d]+$, 3 is just 2 cases, 4 requires some code, but wouldn't be particularly difficult.

Comment: Condition 1 and 2 can be checked by `\\d{6}` regex but rest should be done by some algorithm.

Comment: Add some already done work from your side so it doesn't look like a do my homework question

Comment: While I did not down vote, I would assume you have been down voted as you did not supply sample code showing what you have tried. For instance you could have supplied a snippet that covered cases 1 & 2 using regex (or everything except for the actual regex). This snippet would have given others something to build on for the other cases, instead of having to do all the work like NominSim has done.

Comment: You have only been here a few months, but I am sure you will see over time that the more effort you put into your questions, the better and quicker you will get answers. Don't take down votes personally, but as a sign that maybe you could have asked the question in a better way. Maybe provided a code snippet, or explained what you need in a clearer way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seemed interesting, so I thought I would give it a go. This should do what you are looking for it to do, though I didn't thoroughly test it. There are probably simpler solutions out there.

```
private static boolean validatePW(String pw) {
    if(pw.length() == 6){
        int pwInt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        try{
            pwInt = Integer.parseInt(pw);
            char[] values = pw.toCharArray();
            boolean asc = true;
            boolean dec = true;
            int[] map = new int[10];
            map[values[0]-48] = 1;
            for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
                asc = asc && values[i] - 1 == values[i-1];
                dec = dec && values[i] + 1 == values[i-1];
                map[values[i]-48] ++;
                if(map[values[i]-48] == 3){return false;}
            }
            if(asc || dec){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With so many constraints I think you should validate this using Java.
You can use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) from Apache Commons to help you.